# Meaning of song title まるつけ from the anime Given

Tags: meaning, song-lyrics, anime

As the title suggests, I'd like to know the meaning of the ending song from the anime *Given* titled まるつけ.

Does the first part mean round/circular or more appropriately, calm, since this more of an emotion than "circular" is? I don't know what the second part means.

Below are the lyrics I grabbed from a site (with source info at the end) if it helps in interpreting the meaning.

> 寂しさは凶器だ
>   人を傷つけてしまう
>   それに気付けなくなる
>   愛しさは病気だ
>   胸が苦しくなるよ
>   治し方はないんだ
>
> この日々は奇跡だ
>   でも何かが足りない
>   埋まらない　空欄
>   君は　不思議だ
>   その存在が僕を
>   強くも　弱くもする
>
> 僕らはどうかな　上手いこと
>   「人間」をできてるかな
>   どうかな　どうかな
>   深まりながら　まるつけ
>
> 優しさは積み木だ
>   積み上げれば高くなる
>   だけれど　脆くもなる
>   正しさは正義だ
>   だけど人は踏み外す
>   それを救うのは何？
>
> 僕らはどうかな　上手いこと
>   「恋愛」をできてるかな
>   どうかな　どうかな
>   答えもなく　まるつけ
>
> 僕らはどうかな　ふたりで
>   「人生」をやれるかな
>   どうかな　どうかな
>   願いを込め　まるつけ
>
> 「人生」は天気だ
>   晴れたり降られたりする
>   どちらも起こりうる
>   どうかな　傘なら
>   僕が持っておくから
>   ふたりでひとつになろう？

Source: https://www.lyrical-nonsense.com/lyrics/given/marutsuke/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

「まるつけ」＝「丸付{まるつ}け」

「丸」＝「〇」

「付ける」= "to mark"

「丸を付ける」= "to mark with a circle"

「まるつけ」 is the noun form of above -- "***circling the correct answer***".

In Japanese culture, 「〇」 means "correct" and 「[✖]{ばつ}」 means "incorrect" on tests and quizes.

Thus,  in the song lyrics you provided, 「まるつけ」 would mean something along the lines of "**calling our life, love, way of living, etc. as 'alright'**"

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown. I had looked up 付ける from denshi-jisho, but not one of the definitions was "to mark." The closest I could infer after reading your answer was "to add." Your answer makes the title make sense for me.

Comment: Despite what the word literally says, 丸付け normally refers to a process that includes marking both right and wrong answers as such, and therefore it is synonymous with 採点 and 答え合わせ. In the context of the song it would mean that they are evaluating or checking to see how well they are doing at humaning, loving and living.